# Necessary optimality conditions: $\min_{\phi} \sum_\xi\int_{0}^{1} p(a,\xi) T(V_{w(a,\xi)}[\phi]) da$, where $V[\cdot]$ is an evaluation functional

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, optimal-control, euler-lagrange-equation, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to set up a dynamic optimization problem as follows.

Let $\mathcal{W} := [\underline{w},\overline{w}]$, and $w:[0,1]\times\{0,\dots,N\}\to \mathcal{W}$

\begin{align}
\min_{\phi: \mathcal{W}\to \mathbb{R}} &J[\phi] = \sum_{\xi=0}^N\int_{0}^1p(\xi)p(a)T\left(2\phi(w(a,\xi)) - \phi(\overline{w}) - \phi(\underline{w})\right)da,\\
&\text{s.t.: } \phi'(z)\geq g(z),\,\phi(1)=0,\,\phi'(1)=1,\\&\qquad\text{and } \phi(\overline{w}),\, \phi(\underline{w}) \text{ free}.
\end{align}

We assume, of course, that $1 \in \mathcal{W}$. Moreover, the function $T$ is quasi-convex, and $g$ is known and (strictly) positive.

**What I have tried:**

My first idea was to change the variable $a$ to another variable $z$ and use a regular optimal control formulation, and I think this might work but there are two issues:

1. $w$ is not 1-to-1, and the inverses can get very messy, after dividing into regions where it is indeed 1-to-1.
2. I would like to understand the general case, since in my particular problem I might not know the form of $w$.
3. even after changing the variable, the presence of the function $\phi$ evaluated at the endpoints *inside* the integrals makes it somewhat non-standard, if I'm not mistaken.

My second idea was to try to derive some sort of Euler-Lagrange equation directly from $\phi'$, by noting that:
\begin{equation}
2\phi(w(a,\xi)) - \phi(\overline{w}) - \phi(\underline{w}) = \int_{\underline{w}}^{\overline{w}}\phi'(z)\text{Sgn}(w(a,\xi)-z)dz =: V_{w(a,\xi)}[\phi'],
\end{equation}
so that the optimization problem, in terms of $\phi'(z) := u(z)$ reads:

\begin{align}
\max_{u: \mathcal{W}\to \mathbb{R},\\ \phi(\underline{w}) \in \mathbb{R}} &\tilde{J}[u] = \sum_{\xi=0}^N\int_{0}^1p(\xi)p(a)T\left(V_{w(a,\xi)}[u]\right)da,\,\text{ s.t.: }\\
&\quad u(z)\geq g(z),\,\int_{\underline{w}}^{1}u(z)dz + \phi(\underline{w})=0,\,u(1)=1.
\end{align}

**My questions:**

a. Is this reformulation correct? What would the necessary conditions look like?